# Industrial flash (LED?) for rolling shutter

Tags: led, flash, camera

I am developing industrial monitoring system, at this moment with Raspberry Pi and its camera (this might change if it is not satisfactory). The camera will take still pictures of the scene once in a few seconds. Since the objects are moving, it has shutter time max 1/1000s. After some experiments, I determined I need around 10kLux light source which is either turned on all the time (though without producing excessive heat), which is turned on and off programatically, bracketing the camera action, or one which can be synced with the camera shutter using the camera's chip flash sync.

The camera unfortunately has rolling shutter, so xenon flash tubes are out, AFAIK -- their light interval is probably too short, there would be partial exposure -- but that's just what I understand from readings sources, so I will be glad to be corrected here).

What other flash options do I have? I will be glad to use LED-based flash, but need reliable circuitry around it as well. Ready-made industrial cameras systems costing over $4000 are something I would like to avoid, if possible.

I would like to ask for pointer in which way to go, keywords to search for, or even marketed products which would be suitable. I am personally only moderately skilled in low-level electronics, but have colleagues who know that stuff.

Comment: If you really need 1/1000 sec. exposure in order to "stop" the motion, you should be looking for a sensor that has global shutter capability. Then your flash issue becomes moot.

Comment: no idea where you got the 1ms shutter time for moving, i think 4-5ms is reasonably ok.

Comment: @KyranF: I was considering the motion maxing around .5m/s; thus to limit the blur to 0.5mm, I need at most 1/1000.

Comment: is that relative movement from the camera? further away things are, the less they move relative to the camera.

Comment: Instead of considering expensive or custom flash options with a cheap built-in camera, why not just get a slightly more expensive camera (with a proper shutter instead of a rolling shutter) and a standard flash?

Comment: @KyranF: Static camera, things moving on a conveyor belt.

Comment: @NickJohnson: please suggest a camera that is slightly more expensive, I've just seen tons which were *very* expensive (in k$).

Comment: I don't think you understand, something 10 meters away is moving slower than 1 meter away. If the objects move at 0.5m/s, and you need 1ms shutter time, what if the objects are far away and relative to the camera they only move at 0.1m/s? Anyway how precise do you need this image, if zero blur is acceptable?

Comment: @eudoxos Well, any cheap consumer level DSLR seems like an obvious choice.

Comment: @KyranF the blur will be over different number of pixels depending on the distance, but relative to the object (pellet) size, around 12mm in diameter, it will still be the same 0.5mm. The pictures serve as input to image analysis (determining pellet size distribution), so the edges should be sharp.

Comment: I designed a 3kW strobe light using Cree white LEDs, for 10Hz strobing with a camera sync pulse and dual cameras for mobile robotic stereo vision. My design specs were for 3-5ms pulse duration so that objects can be identified 10 meters away, while the cameras were on the mobile robot moving at 1-2m/s

Comment: I guess your industrial monitoring system is a little different, but anyway it's quite effective to use pulsed white LEDs, and I recommend the Cree brand for the best output. My system produced theoretically in the 50-70k range Lux by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rolling shutter with fast moving objects is just not a good mix.  You don't mention some key elements of your requirements (like imager format, frame rate etc.) so it will be hard to recommend a solution.  It's likely you will need to go to a ILT (Inter Line Transfer) CCD for a global shutter.

You also don't say what control you have over the the rolling rest and the rolling read so again it will be hard to give any recommendations.

The one fall back that you do have is to do the following.
- Set you exposure time to be longer than a frame time (or as long as possible)
- Figure out how to determine when the Imager has finished the rolling reset
- Keep everything in the dark
- Fire your flash once the imager has finished the reset but has not started to read out the imager.
- Read out the imager

Note:
- this will adversely affect your frame rate.

Comment: Resolution around 4Mpix, frame rate once in 5 seconds is enough. I don't think I have control over rolling rest/read with the RPi camera. If you can recommend a global shutter camera with flash sync interface, I will be very happy about that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure I understand the issue, but I'll take a stab at it anyway.

I'm assuming you can get a light source that you can turn on and off with digital logic, and your problem is that the flash sync signal isn't long enough to keep the light on for your image acquisition.

If this is the case, just use the flash sync to trigger a monostable multivibrator (i.e., a one shot) with a pulse long enough to allow the image capture, then use the output of the one shot to turn on your light source.

Not sure you can achieve the same functionality with the Pi alone.  It would be simple on a microcontroller with full interrupt functionality, but then you lose the imaging and file handling convenience of the Pi.  You might consider a Beaglebone Black, which has its own microcontroller (though I haven't read much about using it).

In any case, the one-shot is a one-chip circuit, and shouldn't be burdensome to implement.

Comment: The issue is that on/off light sources (like LED or halogen lamps) don't produce enough light (I need roughly 20kLux, based on preliminary experiments), and the xenon flash pulse is too short to play well with the rolling shutter. So something in-between is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @eudoxos  http://www.ledlight.com/led_200w_high_bay-bridgelux_led_85-265v_ac_45_degree_ul.aspx  I can't do the conversion without knowing your geometry, but is 17Klumen enough for you??

Comment: brute force method, but looks good, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much ambient light there is, one possible solution is to use the fastest X-sync speed the camera is capable of, then fire a xenon flash or several of them in sync.  The flashes will only illuminate the subject for the short 1/1000 second exposure time (make sure the flashes are that short).  If the ambient light is low enough, then very little light in comparison will be captured during the rest of the time the shutter is open but the flashes aren't illuminating the subject.

The extreme case of this is a totally dark room and the shutter always open.  The scene will only be captured during the brief time of the flash.  This is exactly how Doc Egerton made those famous high speed pictures, like a bullet thru a apple, so many years ago.  The mechanical shutter wasn't anywhere near as fast as the exposure time, which came from the speed of the flash, not the speed of the shutter.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. [This](http://www.photobugblog.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/flash-duration.jpg) shows light emission of a xenon tube in time. So the problem is on the contrary that xenons are too fast, and the rolling shutter will cause different exposure at different places of the image.

Comment: @eudoxos: Right, that's why I said to use the mechanical shutter at its X-sync speed, not the fast speed you actually want for the photograph.  The X-sync speed is that speed at which the whole shutter is open at one time.

Answer (score 0):

We replaced an old (strobbing) Xenon flash lamp with a bright white LED.  Flashing it for a few milliseconds every second or so should not be a problem.  For the circuit, I'd do an opamp as voltage controlled current source with a FET as the pass element.  With a little sense resistor to measure the current.  I can scribble out a circuit if you don't know what I mean.  (something like [this](http://www.eeweb.com/electronics-quiz/solve-the-current-through-the-load-of-this-handy-current-source), but it needs a bit more around the feedback path.)

Comment: Does the flashing LED emit more light than when lit continuously? I found 250W LED reflectors giving 25kLux, but they cost over $1000; but if we can get the pulse to be much brigther than continuous light, that would be a big win.

Comment: You can probably run the LED at a higher current.  But I don't know the time frame... I'm guessing a few ms may be pushing it.  (Check the spec sheet of the LED)  We don't use ours above the DC rated current.  (in fact it's run lower... those things are darn bright!)  (10,000 lux is like a bright day outdoors... do you really need that much light?  Maybe a better camera is needed?

Comment: Yep, right, better camera would do, but we try low-budget first; the RPi camera has the "lens" diameter about 2mm, tiny, so it need a lot of light for short exposure... If you know a good camera for decent price, let me know.